# Docker - apt-get install fail

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a pretty easy docker-compose/docker-sync script:

**docker-compose-dev.yml**

```
# this is our development docker-compose building on top of the production docker-compose, just mounting
# the sync image - not redefining anything else

version: "2"
services:
  apache:
    volumes:
      - ./docker-config/vhost:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
      - jettsw53-sync:/var/www/html:nocopy # nocopy is important

# that the important thing
volumes:
  jettsw53-sync:
    external: true
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  apache:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 80:80

  db:
    image: orchardup/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: jettsw53
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM bylexus/apache-php7

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
      curl \
      vim

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/run"]
```

**docker-sync.yml**

```
version: "2"

options:
  verbose: true
syncs:
  jettsw53-sync: # tip: add -sync and you keep consistent names as a convention
    src: './src'
    sync_excludes: ['.git', 'var/cache/*']
```

When I start this setup, I get this error when running apt-get install:

```
Building apache
Step 1/3 : FROM bylexus/apache-php7
 ---> 97d3e723b95a
Step 2/3 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y       curl       vim
 ---> Running in ae4aa07c3b4f
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does no longer have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
Service 'apache' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y       curl       vim' returned a non-zero code: 100
EXCEPTION: #<Docker::Compose::Error: 'up' failed with status 'pid 40288 exit 1': Step 1/3 : FROM bylexus/apache-php7>
MESSAGE: 'up' failed with status 'pid 40288 exit 1': Step 1/3 : FROM bylexus/apache-php7
```

Does anybody know what is happening here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pointing at an unsupported / no longer supported Ubuntu release. Use either

- the 16.04 LTS release, or
- the 17.10 current release

as 16.10 and 17.04 have been (somewhat annoyingly in the case of the latter) been turned off.  FWIW I tend to upgrade every six months on a handful of machines and that generally works just swimmingly.

Comment: That means the ubuntu image that is being used in the docker image (https://github.com/crollalowis/docker-apache-php7) is old? But then I can not use this image and need to create a new one by myself? It's hard to find a proper php7 apache image for docker. I think it's strange because the image says it's using the LTS release.